# Infer interface property type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Say I have this interface and an object that contains that type:

```js
interface IMyData {
    a: TypeA;
    b: TypeB;
    c: boolean;
    d: string;
}

const myObj: { data: IMyData } = {
    data: {
         a: someValueA,
         b: someValueB,
         c: true,
         d: "someValueD"
    }
}
```

Now I would like to get a single property from that object and have the function infer the return type:

```js
function getField(obj: { data: IMyData }, field: keyof IMyData){
    return obj.data[field];
}

const myFieldStr = getField(myObj, "d"); // should infer type string
const myFieldBool = getField(myObj, "c"); // should infer type boolean
```

How can I define the `getField` function so it infers the return types? Right now it would infer `TypeA | TypeB | boolean | string`.

---

Here is another (more complex?) scenario:

```js
interface IMyValue<T> {
    value?: T;
}

interface IMyData2 {
    a?: IMyValue<string>;
    b?: IMyValue<number>;
    c?: IMyValue<boolean>;
    d?: IMyValue<string>;
}

function getValue<T extends keyof IMyData2>(field: T, data: IMyData2) {
    return data[field] ? data[field]!.value : undefined; // this wouldn't compile without '!' mark
}

const testData: IMyData2 = {
    a: { value: 'a' },
    b: { value: 2 },
    c: { value: false },
};

const testValue1 = getValue('a', testData); // i want this to detect as type of `string`
const testValue2 = getValue('b', testData); // i want this to detect as type of `number`
const testValue3 = getValue('b', testData); // i want this to detect as type of `boolean`
const testValue4 = getValue('b', testData); // i want this to detect as type of `undefined`
```

Comment: what are `TypeA`, and `TypeB`? It s not clear why you think `getField` should infer a type of string when you've specified it as a non described type (`TypeA`)

Comment: @DamianGreen why does it matter? They could be anything, the question is about whether or not you can write it so that the compiler can figure it out with asserting the type of the return values manually. It doesn't matter what types are in the sum type.

Comment: It's a bit misleading that you write you expect `string` for `getField(myObj, "b")`. We expect `TypeB` for `"b"`

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing out. Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell the typesystem the exact literal value of `field`. The easiest way to do that is to use a generic function like this:

```
interface IMyData {
    c: boolean;
    d: string;
}

const myObj: { data: IMyData } = {
    data: {
         c: true,
         d: "someValueD"
    }
}

function getField<T extends keyof IMyData>(obj: { data: IMyData }, field: T){
    return obj.data[field];
}

const myFieldStr = getField(myObj, "c"); // should infer type boolean
const myFieldBool = getField(myObj, "d"); // should infer type string
```

Or in the simplest general case:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(obj : T, key : K) {
    return obj[key];
}

const foo = pluck({ bar: "asd", baz: 5 }, "bar"); // infers string
```

Comment: Thank you Tamas! That's exactly what I was looking for. Couldn't wrap up my head around the types..

Comment: Hey @tamas-hegedus, I've added another scenario into my original question (not sure if i should ask it separately). Any idea how to address that? If that's even possible with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to the second (more complex) scenario would be to define a new type which will extract the type from the generic:

```
type GenericOf<S> = S extends IMyValue<infer T> ? T : never;
```

Now you "plug-in" that type your function:

```
function getValue<T extends keyof IMyData2>(field: T, data: IMyData2) {
    // old solution: return data[field] ? data[field]!.value : undefined;
    return data[field]?.value as GenericOf<IMyData2[T]>;
}
```

This will result the return values of the function to be correctly typed:

```
const testValue1 = getValue('a', testData); // string | undefined
const testValue2 = getValue('b', testData); // number | undefined
const testValue3 = getValue('c', testData); // boolean | undefined
const testValue4 = getValue('d', testData); // string | undefined
```

This is not the most elegant solution but it works!