# Typescript typing property getter creator

Tags: typescript

My issue is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974875/typescript-get-object-property-type-from-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930976/infer-interface-property-type-in-typescript) (and probably other places too). I feel like it's a simple Lookup Type issue ([documented here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)). But my use case is slightly different and I cannot get it to work.

I have a function that takes an object of `Type` and returns a "getter" function for this object.
[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKOYRASzwHMAabXAus-AVyICMkmBfANyZMAYwD2eSlCIEA1hADiEYMCSooAHgAq4CAygBpCCCgQAHmrwATOFAUhxAMyi7IAPgAU47gCtybhAAlKjuUJ4O5MYgIShhPr4A2g4AusJiktIcCIjk8OpoWLhQrOwArGVMxYQk5ADkAEI0BHh1AukSUsBQbKoFMvJKKmqIntlIQcKdWRq9I551pXWTmEA) a simple playground.

```
type User = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
};

const makeGetter = <Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type) => (key: Key) => obj[key];

const user: User = {
    age: 55,
    name: 'Brian',
};

const getter = makeGetter(user);
const u = getter('age');
```

However, the selected property is always a union of all possible property types.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your generic will be created on creation of the makeGetter function. At this time `Key`isn't resolved to a specific key yet. Move the generic to the curried function.

```
const makeGetter = <Type extends Object>(obj: Type) => <K extends keyof Type>(key: K) => obj[key]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=98&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKOYRASzwHMAabXAus-AVyICMkmBfANyZMAYwD2eSlCIEA1hADiEYMCSooAHgAq4aBAAeavABM4UAPLcAVhFHAAfAApxN8rsgBKVA60BpKENjMygFEHEAMygPCGcw8j9vFF9XawBtMIBdEQkpYCgOBERyeHU0LFwoVnYAVhqmSsIScgByACEaAjwWgWExSWk2VTKZeSUVNUQnQqRPYVzpDg0hyacW6pa5zCA)

Comment: After meddling with it for a while longer, I reached the same conclusion as well. This way it indeed works.