# infer values from objects using object keys

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Been looking for an answer for this, but couldn't find an exact one.

I have to following code example:

```
interface RowData {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    participate: boolean;
}

const rows: RowData[] = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Dou',
        age: 0,
        participate: true
    }
]

function mapRowsData(key: keyof RowData, rowData: RowData) {
    let value = rowData[key];

    switch(key) {
        case 'firstName': {
            return value.toUpperCase(); // error 1
        }
        case 'age': {
            return value * 2; // error 2
        }
        default: {
            return '-'
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are of the same type:

error1:

```
Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean'.
  Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'number'.(2339)
```

error2:

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.(2362)
```

What's a simple way to make the inference work and identify the value's type according to key? Appreciate.

Comment: I think without something a feature like [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) there's no "simple" way to give types to your code that will do what you want.  I'd suggest giving up on `value` since the correlation in types between `key` and `value` is not trackable by the compiler.  Something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0yMGW).  Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: def did the trick! @jcalz

Answer (score 0):

I tried using type inference similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931114/3261454), but was still getting the same errors as you. As an alternative approach, you could use the key directly in the case statement:

```
function mapRowsData(key: keyof RowData, rowData: RowData) {
    switch(key) {
        case 'firstName': {
            return rowData.firstName.toUpperCase();
        }
        case 'age': {
            return rowData.age * 2;
        }
        default: {
            return '-'
        }
    }
}
```

You could also cast to the expected key type like so:

```
function mapRowsData(key: keyof RowData, rowData: RowData) {
    let value = rowData[key];

    switch(key) {
        case 'firstName': {
            return (value as string).toUpperCase();
        }
        case 'age': {
            return (value as number) * 2;
        }
        default: {
            return '-'
        }
    }
}
```